# Border radius inside of padding on element?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I have a list:

```
<ul class="small-block-grid-3 medium-block-grid-6">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Each `li` has a background image and a border radius of 50% making it a circle:

```
background: url(test.jpg) no-repeat center / cover;
background-origin: content-box;
border-radius: 50%; //other browser prefixes removed for simple example
```

There is padding from the Foundation framework for each `li`, this spaces out the list nicely.

Unfortunately the `border-radius` does not respect the padding, I would like the border radius to be inside of the padding. Is there a way to do this?

I've checked out an answer on SO: [Border-radius and padding not playing nice](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F9409632%2Fborder-radius-and-padding-not-playing-nice&ei=hOBtVOTQAbLjsATJ34LADw&usg=AFQjCNECFftL5pv2lMMhr8RhZpBMAIPE0A&sig2=LeJVpGrulu7mklMHlWQgJA&bvm=bv.80120444,d.cWc) which suggests using margin instead of padding, this would mean overriding Foundation styles which I would rather not do.

Is there another solution?

Comment: You could use a more specific selector something like `li.noPadding` - that way, overriding the default padding on list items will only effect this code

Comment: Why would you need to override the foundation styles? Simply add a margin to the qualifying elements

Comment: @SW4 not ideal as I have to whack in loads of media queries for each foundation breakpoint

Comment: @SW4 also adding a margin screws up the layout, the elements are now too large and are pushed on to each row. So how can I just add a margin to each element without it overspilling?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **background-clip** property and its value `content-box`

**[Demo of 3 possible values in Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPPyjj)**
(dotted and dashed borders didn't show anything useful here so I used a `double` border)

From **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip)**

> The background-clip CSS property specifies whether an element's background, either the color or image, extends underneath its border.

Compatibility is IE9+ and caniuse links to a [polyfill for IE8](https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill) (and IE7? But who cares anymore)